# Why do I get a flask weakref error when importing my SQLAlchemy db from a submodule?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I currently have a flask project set up as follows (I did make a few modifications here to try and get the smallest working example, so some of this may be changed slightly)

```
from extensions import db
def create_api():
   # Create API app
   api = Flask(__name__)

   # Configure... the configs
   api.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get("DB_URL", "default")

   # Register information to run api
   register_extensions(api)
   register_models(api)
   register_urls(api)

   # Return the api object
   return api

create_api().run()
```

My register extension and register models methods look as follows:

```
def register_models(api):
    with api.app_context():
        db.create_all()


def register_extensions(api):
    db.init_app(api)
    bcrypt.init_app(api)
```

The extension module:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

# Establish SQLAlchemy Database extension
db = SQLAlchemy()

# Establish Bcrypt extension for hashing passwords
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
```

My project directory looks something like

```
-FSBS
   -API
      - __init__.py
      - app.py
      - extensions.py
      - routes.py
```

Everything works great like this. However- If I change the import in app.py from
`from extensions import db` to `from FSBS.API.extensions import db`, all my attempts to use db start throwing "KeyError: <weakref at 0x00000251C4B1DAD0; to 'Flask' at 0x00000251C0ED3FA0>".

This is somewhat problematic because I would like to start refactoring my routes into a subfolder, where I **have** to use from `FSBS.API.extensions import db`.

Not only that, but I don't understand why this would make a difference, so any advice on solving this little puzzle would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Same problem here, trying to use `connexion` wrapper with flask-sqlalchemy 3.0.x and openalchemy

Answer (score 1):

I've recently encountered the exact same problem while trying to put my routes into a submodule.

I can't explain why this happens, but from what I can tell, it has something to do with the Flask-SQLAlchemy version - I've initially tried running version 3.0.2.

What solved the problem for me was a downgrade to version 2.5.1

Comment: Apparently the author of the extension started using weak references with the rewrites for compatibility with recent  versions of SQLAlchemy. There might be some subtle bug